# Как добавить 2 разных класса в <div>?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

Помогите пожалуйста. Есть код. Этот меняет класс (настройка в customizer для wordpress) - к примеру, если кнопка справа, то класс `back-to-top-right`

```
wp.customize( 'back_to_top_align', function( value ) {          
    value.bind( function ( to ) {
        $( "#toTop" ).removeClass ( function ( index, className ) {
            return ( className.match (/(^|\s)back-to-top-\S+/g) || [] ).join(' ');
        });         
        $( '#toTop' ).addClass( to );   
    } );
} );
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Этот код меняет класс если кнопка круглая (`back-to-top-type-circle`), если квадратная (`back-to-top-type-square`).

```
wp.customize( 'back_to_top_type', function( value ) {           
    value.bind( function ( to ) {
        $( "#toTop" ).removeClass ( function ( index, className ) {
            return ( className.match (/(^|\s)back-to-top-type-\S+/g) || [] ).join(' ');
        });         
        $( '#toTop' ).addClass( to );   
    } );
} );
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том, что если я меняю расположение, то класс `back-to-top-type-circle` или `back-to-top-type-square` пропадает.

Я не знаю как это все вместе сложить чтобы оба класса сохранялись когда я нажимаю на любую из этих кнопок.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Должны оба класса быть и менять свои окончания.

Спасибо.

Comment: да, они переключаются. все отлично работает по отдельности,  но когда мне нужно и переместить вправо/влево и поменять форму, то один из классов пропадает, как будто бы не сохраняетсяю

Comment: вы не пытались найти решение по определению класса попроще чем регулярные выражения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может кому-то пригодится

```
$( "#toTop" ).removeClass ( function ( index, className ) {
            return ( className.match (/(^|\s)back-to-top-(left|center|right)/g) || [] ).join(' ');
        });
        $( '#toTop' ).addClass( to );
```

у меня так сработало.